# Flex security error, cannot load data

Tags: apache-flex, cross-domain, facebook

I get a really strange security error when trying to load data from one URL to another.  Essentially my facebook canvas URL points to `http://www.tonyamoyal.com/stuff/path/` and that has an fb:swf tag which points to `http://www.tonyamoyal.com/stuff/path/Quiz.swf`.  The facebook app loads fine but when I try to call a service that resides on another URL, I get a security error:

```
http://www.tonyamoyal.com/stuff/path/Quiz.swf cannot load data from http://www.somedomain.com/path/path/service.aspx
```

The cross-domain on tonyamoyal.com is set up to allow all domains to pass. The cross-domain on somedomain.com has a line specifically allowing calls from www.tonyamoyal.com:

```
<allow-access-from domain="www.tonyamoyal.com" />
```

Any idea why there would be a security issue here?

Comment: is there any chance that you are missing the www part and using just `tonymoyal.com` in the swf embed tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At application startup try to load the policy file by doing:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.somedomain.com/crossdomain.xml");
```